# How to extract the field values from a dataset in spark using scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka, functional-programming

I have a dataframe which reads streams from kafka as a source and it is then converted to a dataset after applying schema, now how to get that particular field value from the dataset to work with it?

```scala
case class Fruitdata(id:Int, name:String, color:String, price:Int)

//say this function reads streams from kafka and gives me the dataframe
val df = readFromKafka(sparkSession,inputTopic)

//say this converts dataframe to a dataset with schema defined accordingly
val ds: Dataset[Fruitdata] = getDataSet[Fruitdata](df,schema)

//and say the incoming stream data is - 
//"{"id":1,"name":"Grapes","color":"Green","price":15}"
//Now how to get a particular field like name, price and so on

//this doesn't works, it says "Queries with streaming sources must be executed with writeStream.start()"
ds.first()
//same here
ds.show

//also can i get the complete string as input,this gives me Dataset[String]
val ds2  = ds.flatMap((f: Fruitdata)=>List(s"${f.id},${f.name}"))
```

Comment: Need to show more code.

Comment: You can't use actions like `count`, `show`, `first` with a streaming dataset. You have to use an output sink as described [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#output-sinks). If you want to just show the dataframe you can use the Console sink. If you want to run different actions you can use the ForeachBatch sink and treat the dataframe as in the batch case

Comment: could you please give an example performing a small operation on streaming dataset for the example above@vinsce

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because you're trying to read from kafka.

When you run with Spark streaming, I think you cannot run few of the commands as they are related to streaming sources. For example, if you are reading from kafka, there is nothing like first, because it is a micro batch and first refers to each micro batch. Please, try something like "console" sink to output your records to console. Also make sure to read few sample records and not real kafka feed.